# Marketing Cloud Contact Data Decision Split

Tags: salesforce, cloud

A year ago, my colleagues decided to split the Contacts object in Salesforce into Leads and Accounts (this was before I joined the company). Subsequently, they stopped the syncing of the Contacts object in Marketing Cloud via the connector and only left Leads and Accounts. In the data model, however, the old configuration remained the same with the Contact -> Account relationship. I have no information on how and why this was done as the main person responsible went off to have a baby.

As we are trying to make the decision splits in the journeys based on Contact data work (as directly selected in the synchronised DE model), we decided to sync the Contacts object again, which resulted in over 600k duplicates being created (we will delete them) with a ContactKey - they are duplicates as they are already being synced from Accounts_Salesforce DE. We wanted to check if this was the reason the decision split did not work (that it's because it was missing the contact part and somehow can't understand where to look).

Well, it still doesn't work, which brings me to this forum to ask - does contact data decision split (when instructed to check the synchronised DE) just doesn't work when a DE is a starting point, as opposed to Salesforce data? Do we need to sync this Contacts object at all, or just get rid of it as the data model is already set in Salesforce? Thank you!

Comment: You may have more luck with Marketing Cloud questions at dedicated https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/. StackOverflow is more about code problems than config.